# Canceling a function call from inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm currently coding a rock, paper, scissors game from The Odin Project. It's a 1 player (user input) against a simple computer.

My game goes 5 rounds and instead of using a for-loop, I want (and am allowed to, according to The Odin Project) to use a function call 5x

However, I want the game/function to stop, once either player reaches 3 points, e.g.: someone wins 3 rounds in a row

```js
if (playerScore >= 2) {
  console.log(`Game finished! You won!`);
  return;
}
if (cpuScore >= 2) {
  console.log(`Game finished! You lost!`);
  return;
}
```

I tried using `return` thinking I'd be able to "cancel" the function call(s) but apparently it doesn't stop getting the function called from outside, it continues to ask the player for new inputs since it goes 5 rounds

Is it even possible to cancel a function call from inside a function ?

Here's a snippet of my code. The playRound() function is inside the game() function, which is called at the very bottom 5 times.

```js
function game() {
  console.log(playRound());   
   function playRound()  {  

     // does something  

   if (playerScore >= 2) {   
     console.log(Game finished! You won!);   
     return;  
   } 
   if (cpuScore >= 2) {   
     console.log(Game finished! You lost!);   
     return; 
    }  
  } 
}  
game(); 
game(); 
game(); 
game(); 
game();
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: So you would like to brake a loop that calls a function from within that function?

Comment: Please include the code that keeps calling the function, you probably need to break out of THAT code too.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to cancel a function call from inside a function?

Yes, and you're doing it. When a `return` statement is reached, the function ends.

However, that does not affect subsequent calls of the same function.

```
game();
game();
```

Here, the first call to `game()` might end abruptly because some condition became true and `return` was hit. The next `game()` does not care *why* the previous one has ended, it just runs because it's the next piece of code in line.

If you want to make that difference, you have to return *something* and make the next line conditional. You could decide that you want `game()` to return `true` when the game is over.

```
var gameOver;

gameOver = game();
if (!gameOver) gameOver = game();
if (!gameOver) gameOver = game();
if (!gameOver) gameOver = game();
if (!gameOver) gameOver = game();
```

This would play a maximum of 5 rounds, and stop any further calls to `game()` as soon as the game is over.

But it is also awfully repetitive, which is why these things are usually done in some sort of a loop.

```
var gameOver;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    gameOver = game();
    if (gameOver) break;
}
```

or, shorter

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (game()) break;
}
```